# Azure DevOps: Bypass Branch Policies is not working on new branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, push, build-pipeline

Due to a quirk of out build process I need to update a file in the build branch during the build process. As I have Pull Request Branch Policies set and created a specific account for the build process and gave it "Bypass polices when pushing" permission. I then have a power shell script that uses that account to updates the file in question and do a commit and push during the build. This all works fine on the original branch.

I needed to create a second branch for client specific work, so I cloned the branch and set the build policies and security to the same values (as far as I can tell). 
However the powershell script fails on the push with: **TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.**

[image: Security Settings]

[image: build log]

I've gone over the security settings for the two branches and they are the same (as far as i can  tell).

Comment: Did you try to push code from Head to Development2 branch? What about merge directly with UI? Does it limited by policy? If yes, you'd better check the setting of policy.

Comment: Does that user can push changes through visual studio or git push command? What's your powershell script code?